# Can not save with aviary

Tags: php, javascript, save, aviary

I am facing a problem because I can't save my edited image, I put this code in index.php

```
<?php
    $image_data = file_get_contents($_REQUEST["Url"]);
    file_put_contents("photo.jpg",$image_data);
?>
```

But I have an error :

```
 Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Filename cannot be empty in index.php on line 40
```

If I put the direct link to the edited image it works.

Regards

Comment: `$_REQUEST["Url"]` is empty. How/where are you passing `Url`?

Comment: Aviary makes a HTTP POST so I try to retrieve this URL
    `http://www.aviary.com/web/documentation#saving`